# Samsung Emulator Skins Not Showing in AVD Dropdown

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device, samsung-mobile

I want to create an AVD with the Pre built skins available from Samsung like the S2. So I've downloaded them them their website here: http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks

I unzip, place them in platforms->android-x->skins. But when I create a new AVD, they don't appear in the drop down box no matter which "target" is select. Here are a few things I've tried:

1. Restarted eclipse
2. Changed the manifest version in the skins to match the sdk version
3. Tried only with the latest sdk versions

None of these are working. Does anyone know how I can go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this 
http://developer.samsung.com/remotetestlab/rtlDeviceList.action

This will allow you to use Samsung emulators for 30 mins - 2 hours.